# Do you know any .xry reader for MacOS/*BSD or Linux?

Tags: mobile, forensics, file-types

I am looking for a [.xry](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/.XRY) reader (software) that works on mac/*bsd/linux in order to perform a forensic analysis. Can you suggest one?

Answer (score 2):

Xry only works on XP sp3, and 32 bit Vista or Win7. It doesn't like 64bit OS.